# FileNotFoundException keeps coming up

Tags: java, object, deserialization

I'm making a program where I have to make a file and then deserialize the object in that file. When I name the file something, such as "contacts.dat", I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

The code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputstring = Input.getString("Please enter the name of the file containing the contacts: ");
    TreeMap< String, Contact > contactlist = null;

    ObjectInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputstring)));
        contactlist = (TreeMap< String, Contact >) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | EOFException emptyexcptn) {
        System.out.println("The file provided is currently empty.");
        contactlist = new TreeMap< String, Contact >();
    }
    catch(IOException ioexcptn) {
        ioexcptn.printStackTrace(System.out);
        System.out.println("Error reading file: " + inputstring);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Here's what the exception prints:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: contacts.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
>   at UnitEight.AssignmentEight.main(AssignmentEight.java:16)
>     Error reading file: contacts.dat

Comment: give full path of the file and try

Comment: It's looking in the current directory for that file. Like dev said, you always want to use full paths. BTW, also you should always close resources (files, streams) in a finally block, so that if an exception gets thrown stuff is cleaned up. Remember any line of code can throw an exception (out of memory, null ptr, etc), and you should write defensive code under that assumption. Failing to use 'finally' blocks is a huge source of bugs on much code.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` does **not** mean `"The file provided is currently empty."` Don't lie to yourself with error messages. Print the exception itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument to `new FileInputStream()` is `String inputstring = Input.getString("Please enter the name of the file containing the contacts: ");`...if `Input.getString` returns the path for the file then you are pointing to the wrong path anyway.

Print the result of `Input.getString()`...if any and that would give you a clue what's going on there.

Answer (score -1):

From the API docs -

Constructor Detail

```
FileInputStream
```

> public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException

Creates a FileInputStream by opening a connection to an actual file, the file named by the path name name in the file system. A new FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection.

First, if there is a security manager, its checkRead method is called with the name argument as its argument.

If the named file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.

Parameters:name - the system-dependent file name.Throws:FileNotFoundException - if the file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading.SecurityException - if a security manager exists and itscheckRead method denies read access to the file.

**To summarize in to a working example**:

When you are using the FileInputStream(String filename), try it by specifying the full (absolute) path to the file so your program can find it. Ex: if your text.dat file was on a shared drive Z: your String you would have to pass as a parameter to the constructor would be

"Z:\\text.dat" instead of using an OS specific slash character it is better to use File.separator in the above example it would look like "Z" + File.separator + "text.dat".

Comment: 70% pointless quotation, and the summary is wrong. You don't needto use a full path name. You just need to use a *correct* path name: if relative, relative to the current working directory. The slash character `/` is not "OS-specific" in Java.

Comment: I was trying highlight items where individuals usually go astray. Using the API is always the best approach to learning how classes work. No you don't have to use File.separator though it is better practice then using the forward slash. No you don't have to use a full path but many newer programmers don't fully grasp the idea of relative path to their working directory and again if you know your full path and you try it that way you will for sure no you are attempting to access the correct file.

Comment: So when you say "you need to specify the full path", what you mean is really "you don't have to use a full path". Make up your mind.

Comment: Edit made but you and many others don't have to be a jerk when commenting on solutions provided. People join this site to get answers from subject matter experts. To keep that alive users of this forum should welcome collaboration from new comers not bash them and their questions/comments/solutions yes there is a standard being kept with the quality of information provided but that can be done in a way that is welcoming.